# C++ prime loop test executes in false manner

Tags: c++, for-loop, primes

I'm currently taking on some challenges and looking for stuff to do to test my very new abilities in C++, and I decided to do mostly math, in this case the euler problems. Below is some code to find the greatest prime factor of a given number, however for some reason it does not go into the for loop, I have even run `cout << "Test" << endl;` but it wont print the statement, why is this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int ReturnPFactors(int number)
{
    int Factor{};
    int thisnum = number;
    for (int x = 0; x < thisnum; x++)
    {
        cout << "Here" << endl;
    }
    return Factor;
}

bool isPrime(int n)
{
    // Corner case 
    if (n <= 1)
        return false;

    // Check from 2 to n-1 
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++)
        if (n % i == 0)
            return false;

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    //should be looking for 6857
    int Number = 600851475143;
    cout << ReturnPFactors(Number) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

if you have any questions I will be on for the next 30 or so minutes (from this post), before I sleep.

Comment: Assuming you are supplying positive value for `n`, the code after the first `if` should execute.   From your description, however, I suspect the code you have posted here differs from your actual code.   My guess is that there is a misplaced `;` after the `if` which causes `return false` to be executed unconditionally.

Comment: Your code [looks good](https://wandbox.org/permlink/kp0eroYmAGElpXYd). Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including the caller of `isPrime()`.

Comment: reposted, forgot 90% of the actual code, sorry about that

Comment: `600851475143` is too large for `int` in typical environment, which is 32-bit long and can store upto about `2000000000`.

Comment: `isPrime` is never called in your code.

Comment: isprime is not currently used, Im having an issue with the execution of the for loop. if I specify a certain number, per say 234829202, it will execute, but when I specify the specific number (int Number), it will not execute the for loop and instead skips strait to the end

Comment: Thank you, I will run it as a float now MikeCAT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`600851475143` is too large for `int` type in typical environment, which is 32-bit long and can store upto `2147483647`.

`600851475143` in binary is `1000 1011 1110 0101 1000 1001 1110 1010 1100 0111`.

In typical environment, it is truncated to 32-bit long: `1110 0101 1000 1001 1110 1010 1100 0111`

The top bit of this is `1`, so it is treated as negative number in typical environment.

Threfore, `i < thisnum` becomes false and the loop body won't be executed.

You should use `long long`, which is at least a 64-bit long, and `600851475143LL` with prefix `LL`, which stands for `long long`.